# What's a good way to store unchanging variables in a C# project?

Tags: c#, xml, variables

I'm just learning C#, so pardon my n00bness, please.

- We use Visual Studio 2012 to put together a C#/Selenium project for automated testing.
- We have three credit card processors.

I want to store the login credentials, test settings, and test payment items for each processor.  I could do this in Python in a minute, using a dict:

```
processorCreds = {
    'ProcOne': {
        'website': '[url]',
        'username': '[username]',
        'password': '[password]'
    },
    'ProcTwo': {
        'website': '[url]',
        'username': '[username]',
        'password': '[password]'
    },
}
```

And then I'd just call it when I need it:

```
def openProcessor(procName):
    urllib2.urlopen(processorCreds[procName]['website'])

openProcessor('ProcTwo')
```

I want this in C#, basically.  I will only rarely need to change these credentials, and they'll be used in multiple test cases, so I want to be able to pull the information wherever I need it.

What would be the best way for me to put this together?  Should I use an XML file, or can this be in a class, or...?

**[EDIT]** The alternative I see is that we set the variables each time we have a test case, which doesn't seem... object-oriented.  Or, I suppose I could put the variables on the [Processor]Portal.cs pages...  I was just hoping for a way to put alla this in one place with a minimum of fuss, for our occasional "this works for every processor" tests.

(Also this is totally test data, and would be accessible to the same folk who can already see it now, so I'm not worried.)

Comment: Where do you need the values to be accessible? Inside a method? A class? An assembly?

Comment: could you not store the values in the `Properties-> Settings.settings`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

.NET offers many ways of storing constant or nearly constant data: you have a choice among multiple ways of reading XML files, configuration files, resource files with your own format, and so on. If you would like to define a structure like yours in code, you can use `IDictionary`:

```
internal static readonly IDictionary<string,dynamic> ProcessorCreds =
    new Dictionary<string,dynamic> {
        {"ProcOne", new {
            Website = "[url]",
            Username = "[username]",
            Password = "[password]"
        },
        {"ProcTwo", new {
            Website = "[url]",
            Username = "[username]",
            Password = "[password]"
        }
    };
```

This creates an instance of `Dictionary` that maps `string` objects to anonymous objects with three properties - `Website`, `Username`, and `Password`. Since objects that go in belong to an anonymous class (note the lack of class name between `new` and the opening curly brace) the value type of the dictionary is defined as `dynamic`. This would let you add more attributes in the future without changing anything else.

You can use `ProcessorCreds` like this:

```
urlopen(ProcessorCreds[procName].Website);
```

Comment: I am a MORON.  I forgot entirely about app.config!  Thank you!!

Answer (score 2):

You can put them in App.Config( Web.Config) in the appsettings section and use the configurationmanager to get he values as shown in the example below

```
<appSettings>
    <add key="username" value="me" />
    <add key="password" value="getmein" />
</appSettings>
```

In the code you will have the following

```
string username=ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["username"];
```

Comment: This assumes a single processor

Answer (score 1):

There are a lot of different ways to do this. You could store the data in a static readonly dictionary.

```
public static readonly Dictionary<int, int> MY_DICTIONARY;
```

And place this inside a static class available throughout your project.

You could also store data in the Properties settings.settings file.

Generally, in my C# code I try to avoid global data and instead pass information when it is needed. This allows for code that is more easily tested.

Comment: I definitely would as well!  This is just rarely-if-ever changing data; the most frequent changes are changed passwords, which happen about twice a year.  The last time we changed any login creds _apart_ from the password, it was such a huge deal that it slowed us down for two months.  :wry:

Comment: You can't have `const readonly`. It's one or the other. And since you can't initialize a const Dictionary, I suspect you meant `public readonly Dictionary...`

Comment: @JimMischel Thanks! I actually meant `static readonly` since the question seemed to be looking for a static solution. Updated.

Answer (score 1):

Using C# or Python does not change the answer to this question substantially. If using a mutable in-memory data structure like a dictionary did the trick fine for you in Python, then you can just do the same in C#.

A similar answer uses dynamic, but it is more idiomatic and there are many advantages in C# to favor using static typing, like so:

```
public class Processor {
    public Uri Website { get; private set; }
    public string Username { get; private set; }
    public string Password { get; private set; }
    public Processor(Uri website, string username, string password) {
        Website = website;
        Username = username;
        Password = password;
    }
}

var processorCreds = new Dictionary<string, Processor> {
    { "ProcOne", new Processor(new Uri("[url]"), "[username]", "[password]") },
    { "ProcTwo", new Processor {new Uri("[url]"), "[username]", "[password]") }
};
```

which case be used as

```
processorCreds["ProcOne"].Website
```

Answer (score 0):

Your question has more security and procedural implications than technical.

Since you're saving usernames and passwords for payment processing, there're all kinds of risks to storing these where they are publicly available.    Do you need PCI compliance in your business?  Given that this is security information, don't you want to keep them under lock-and-key to some extent?   Perhaps keep them in a database, or encrypted in some way.

If there's no such issue, your appConfig file is probably the best bet:  you can define them in your project, and retrieve them using the ConfigurationManager class.  The will be stored in the XML file that is deployed along with your application.   In plain text.

Comment: These items are also stored on our internal wiki, which is accessible to the same folk as could see them in the repo, so I'm not too concerned about it.  I'd probably do ANYTHING ELSE in case of working with actual real data, but this is deliberate test data, so... enh.

Answer (score 0):

Put them in a static dynamic variable - this is the most pythonish way to do it, although it's not idiomatic c#

```
static dynamic processorCreds =new {
    ProcOne= new {
        website= "[url]",
        username= "[username]",
        password= "[password]"
    },
    ProcTwo= new {
        website= "[url]",
        username= "[username]",
        password= "[password]"
    },
}
```

You can then access it using `var s = (string) processorCreds.ProcTwo.website;`